# How can I configure OrientDB as the default database in Moqui?

Tags: moqui

Instead of using MySQL or any other RDBMS as my database, can I configure OrientDB to be the default database.

If yes, what will be the changes that would be required in the configuration files in Moqui.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Moqui to use OrientDB for all entities following the example OrientDB ("nosql" group) in MoquiDefaultConf.xml. However, it won't work beyond entities that are only used with simple DB operations because OrientDB doesn't support various things in SQL, including joins. I tried this recently for the fun of it and ran into this and a few other problems. OrientDB is not meant to be a drop-in replacement for SQL relational databases.

On a side note, Moqui (latest in GitHub, not yet released) now uses H2 for the default embedded database and it is MUCH faster than Derby. On my laptop I'm getting around 30k db ops per second (inserts and updates, deletes are much faster) with H2 versus 15k with Derby.

If you want something faster than MySQL, try Percona (both the DB and the performance profiling tools).